# Standard Way to Read Data from USB Bar code Devices C#

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

How can i read data from USB bar code devices in **a read only** text box field in c#?

All possible ways to read from bar code devices work just like a standard keyboard device which means that text box field must be enabled & editable.

Is there any standard way to read data from any USB bar code devices (like TWAIN & WIA for imaging devices)? or i have to get the SDK for each bar code device to deal with the device via virtual Serial port?

Comment: Capture the key events at the form level (KeyPreview), insert into a label/readonly textbox.

Comment: but this way will allow the user to input data using the keyboard which should be disabled

Comment: I don't think you can differ between normal keyboardstrokes and the reader. There is no difference fo the pc.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question...  Is the problem that the control you are trying to enter a bar code in to is readonly, or is the problem that the scanner isn't acting like a keyboard?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I think his problem is that the scanner IS acting like a keyboard an he wants to differentiate between them.

Comment: The scanner acts like the keyboard (no problem in that), but i should read data from the scanner ONLY and DISABLE reading data from standard keyboard

Comment: The scanner IS a keyboard as far as the computer is concerned.  The scanner is presenting a USB HID (Human Interface Device) Id that tells the computer to treat it like a keyboard.  Unless the scanner is capable of some other non-standard input method there is no way to differentiate it from an actual keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I did this successfully using a keyboard raw input. Library for manipulation with it you can find here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

P.S. But some code in this library not correct. I'll want to fork it on github and fix some bugs. I'll notify you when it will be done.

Example of use: https://gist.github.com/frydaykg/0dd3c06e6e91c28d6a4e
And constructor of it. Some details i comments:

```
var keyboardScaner = new KeyboardScaner(form, Session.KeyboardName);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the scanner returning a USB HID that differentiates it from a "real" keyboard?  If the scanner says "I'm a keyboard" I don't see how you could tell the difference.

Comment: I use Keyboard.DeviceName. It is system name and as I understand it is impossible that two devices will have same name.

Comment: And a little trick. I store name of device that will used on login form. And I 'believe' that it is keyboard name. I think it is rare situation when first signal from HID device on login form will be scaner.

Comment: I will check this solution

Comment: ok, i checked this way. Here is the result of reading a simple bar code (74600120) it gave me this result: (D7D7D4D4D6D6D0D0D0D0D1D1D2D2D0D0ENTERENTER)

Comment: D7D7 - 7, D4D4 - 4, and so on

Comment: @MohamedAl-Hosary, if you think that my answer helped you, please +1 it. If you think that my answer is solution, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

While Keyboard emulation is the most common method for barcode reader input, Serial emulation may often give better results in a full client scenario.

The reason for this is that keyboard emulation merges the barcode data stream into the keyboard input stream, making it difficult to separate the two from a processing standpoint.  You have to make sure that the text focus is in the field you want before scanning, and as you've noted, it has to be a writable field.

The advantage with USB barcode readers is that most can be switched from keyboard to serial with just a simple config change.  You might want to try serial emulation and see if it gives you superior results.

Comment: I am searching about serial emulation now, but i don't think that there is a standard way that can work with all types of bar code devices

Comment: Generally: 1)open the serial port that the device is configured for   2) read serial input (normally each barcode will end with a delimiter)   3) Pass barcode to handler function.

Comment: the problem is to configure any bar code device to work in serial mode (i think this requires SDK from the manufacturer)

Comment: Serial should not require an SDK of any kind.  You should simply open a serial port connection and read the data.  DotNet already supports serial ports.